# How can I dynamically add Views that use XML Layouts to the ContentView?

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout

Within my main Activity, I create a FrameLayout with child Views and set it as the ContentView.  Now, staying within the same Activity, after onCreate() has executed fully, I need to be able to add and remove child Views from the FrameLayout, dynamically.  I achieved this by using a Handler to pause the main Thread and then add or removed the child Views as needed.

This all works great when I am dealing with Views that I programmatically create, but when I attempt to do the same with a View that uses a XML layout, I get a Null Pointer Exception from the ViewGroup that I am trying to add to the FrameLayout.

Are there specific steps I can use to achieve this without the use of Fragments?

I can elaborate more if some don't understand what I am asking.  I could provide code chunks if it would help but I think most will get the gist of what I am doing from my short explanation.  I am just looking for someone to point me into the right direction.

Here is the LogCat chunk for the exception taht was thrown:

```
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1821)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at com.beastcodes.framework.impl.AndroidGame.addScreenFragment(AndroidGame.java:207)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at com.beastcodes.framework.impl.AndroidGame.addAllScreenFragments(AndroidGame.java:213)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at com.beastcodes.framework.impl.AndroidGame.access$2(AndroidGame.java:211)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at com.beastcodes.framework.impl.AndroidGame$3.run(AndroidGame.java:61)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
11-15 13:40:42.977: E/AndroidRuntime(14956):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the exception from logcat.  And `I achieved this by using a Handler to pause the main Thread` is both unnecessary and potentially harmful.  I think Android should make you have to go through enormous hoops to use sleep() in a UI thread.

Comment: I will post the LogCat when I get back to my system, but all it says is that the ViewGroup that I am attempting to add to the FrameLayout is null.  Also, I don't understand the potential harm in using a Handler to achieve this? I was actually under impression that this was the only way of going about it without switching to a new activity.  How else would I be able to create a View in a separate thread and then load it into the ContentView of the main thread so that the new View is displayed?

Comment: You just add the child view then invalidate() the parent.

Comment: It's harmful because it stops your activity from responding to Android and can result in an ANR, Application Not Responding, errors.  It's also bad for the user experience.  But we'll wait for the edit and see.

Comment: I added the LogCat in my edit, but the answer taht katzoft gave was the solution to my problem.  I was not properly inflating the layout before adding it to the FrameLayout.  I understand your suggestion of evoking invalidate(), but that is only viable if the work is being performed in the UI Thread.  The View I am trying to add is being created by another thread and as per the Android documentation, that View can only by added the the UI Thread through the use of a Handler.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.  I read from your question that you were using a Handler to pause the UI thread.  My mistake, but I'm pleased it's working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inflate views from XML using a LayoutInflater before adding them to the FrameLayout.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what was needed.  I misunderstood the purpose of the LayoutInflater but it was exactly what I was missing.  Everything is working now.